# How to check theano version on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, theano

I am trying to check my theano version on Ubuntu. I haven't found any useful answer on Google yet. Do you know how I can check my theano version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Import theano 
theano.__version__
```

This should give you the version

Answer (score 9):

`pip show theano` would return the summary of the theano version installed